# set image to label through css in gwt project

Tags: css, gwt

I am using gwt project. In which I have different type of label

1. question
2. answer
3. auther

all of label has common css that is as follows

```
labelCss  {
          background: url("images/img1.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 
                50% transparent;

          background-color: #F2F6F9;
          font-size: 13px;
          margin: 7px 2px 4px 1px;
          padding-bottom: 3px;
          padding-left: 8px;
          padding-top: 6px
          }
```

I want to change image as type of label change .
Is it possible using single css property. or I am doing something  wrong.

If anyone knows please reply

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a .label for the general styling, but you will need a special class for each type of label, where you specify which image is going to present. Small example:

```
#inicio li {
  display: block;
  width: 177px;
  height: 76px;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 0;
  float: left
}
#inicio #ini1 {
  background: url(/imgs/Inicio1.jpg);
}
#inicio #ini2 {
  background: url(/imgs/Inicio2.jpg);
}
#inicio #ini3 {
  background: url(/imgs/Inicio3.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you have multiple CSS classes or you use JS to switch images.

For instance:

```
.generalLabel
      {
      background-color: #F2F6F9;
      font-size: 13px;
      margin: 7px 2px 4px 1px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      padding-left: 8px;
      padding-top: 6px
      }

.label1
      {
      background: url("images/img1.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 
            50% transparent;
      }


.label2
      {
      background: url("images/img2.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 
            50% transparent;
      }
```

Then you can use `class="generalLabel label1"` or `class="generalLabel label2"` on the element that you want to style.

The other option would be to use JS and change the image URL based on the type, but I would not suggest to do that unless there is a very specific reason (and I cannot think of one) for not using CSS only.